# Improving '% LIKE %' Query on Firebird Database

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-like

**Situation:**

I am trying to write a efficient query using "LIKE" statement to look after a piece of text into a column with short texts.

**Model:**

```
Table 'EVENTSGENERAL' : { ID (KEY), GENERATOR_ (FK), DATETIME, COMPUTERNAME, OSLOGIN, DBLOGIN, INFOTYPE, INFO }

Table 'EVENTSGENERATORS' : { ID (KEY), GENERATOR_ (FK), SHORTNAME, LONGNAME }

Table 'EVENTSINFOTYPES'  : { ID (KEY), GENERATOR_ (FK), VERSION_, INFOTYPE, DESCRIPTION }
```

Indexes : `EVENTSGENERAL.GENERATOR`, `EVENTSGENERAL.DATETIME`, `EVENTSINFOTYPES.INFOTYPE`
All Ascending.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT FIRST @first SKIP @skip A.ID,B.LONGNAME,  A.DATETIME, A.COMPUTERNAME,A.OSLOGIN, A.DBLOGIN, C.DESCRIPTION, A.INFO
FROM EVENTSGENERAL A JOIN EVENTSGENERATORS B ON B.GENERATOR_ = A.GENERATOR_
JOIN EVENTSINFOTYPES C ON C.GENERATOR_ = A.GENERATOR_ AND C.INFOTYPE = A.INFOTYPE
WHERE C.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%VALUE%'
```

**Problem:**

This query will run on very large databases. Is there any way I can improve it? I am using a Firebird database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unfortunately not, because you use wildcards (`%`) on both sides of the `LIKE` keyword. The leading (beginning) wildcard means that no index can be used to help improve the search speed, and therefore every row has to be examined to see if it meets the criteria.

You can speed things  up somewhat by changing to `LIKE 'VALUE%'` instead; an index can at least be used to limit the rows being searched to those starting with `VALUE`.

Comment: What would change if i use 'LIKE%' instead ? Would it be faster ?

Comment: If you mean LIKE 'VALUE%', you should be able to index VALUE for some performance gains. You can try creating the index and then doing Filebird's equivalent of an "explain plan".

Comment: Edited to include `LIKE 'VALUE%'` effect on query speed.

Comment: Indeed, it used the index i created when i used the query without the first `WildCard`. Thanks for the help @KenWhite

Answer (score 3):

Full text search (using `%VALUE%`) is slow, because there is no efficient way to do that. It's like grabbing a dictionary to make a list of all words that *contain* the letter Q. That takes forever. On the other hand, if you just look for `VALUE%` it's a lot easier (if the search field is indexed). It's like making a list of all words that *start with* the letter Q. That's easy if the words are alphabetically sorted (like they are in a dictionary). You can easily find the first and last words, and you can be sure that you need everything in between and nothing else.

Some databases allow a full text search, they can index each word in a column, but only the full word. So searching for `%q%` still would be slow, and searching for `q%` would be faster. I'm not sure whether or not Firebird supports it.

If you have a large database and you want to be able to search for `%q%`, you should look into other, specialized solutions, like [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) or [Xapian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xapian)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation,it ended up indexing the database and using the `Word%` query to speed things up. It is not what i wanted,but at least helps for now.
After the first release i may check lucene to see if it fits my needs. 
Thanks again !

Comment: I see what is the problem  "El Corte Inglés"   if i writte "el" is there a way to incremente serch for word´s Capital or Not